# Upload an image to Google Drive with OCR and convert to Doc

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I want to upload an image to Google Drive with OCR function and convert it to Google Doc. I am using this method

```
public static File UploadFile(DriveService Service, string UploadFile, string Parent)
    {

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(UploadFile))
        {
            File body = new File();
            body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(UploadFile);
            body.Description = "File uploaded by Diamto Drive Sample";
            body.MimeType = GetMimeType(UploadFile);
            body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = Parent } };

            // File’s content.
            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(UploadFile);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
            try
            {
                FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = Service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(UploadFile));
                request.Ocr = true;
                request.OcrLanguage = "he";
                request.Convert = true;
                return request.ResponseBody;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + UploadFile);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

and I call it via this line

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File newFile = DriveHelper.UploadFile(service, @"E:\myImage.png", myFolderId);
```

My problem is: `request.ResponseBody` returns `null` but when I remove this lines

```
 request.Ocr = true;
 request.OcrLanguage = "he";
 request.Convert = true;
```

My file uploaded successfully
and `request.ResponseBody` returns `File` Object

Answer (score 0):

This is missing the Upload function.

```
request.Upload();
return request.ResponseBody;
```

Reference link: http://anthonygiretti.com/category/google-api/